# XML Parsing Error: junk after document element. Google maps database interaction

Tags: php, mysql, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi so I'm trying to pull data from a database to be used with Google Maps following the advice from a Google developers article: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3. I have copied their exact code in an attempt to just get a start before manipulating it but it keeps throwing the following error: XML Parsing Error:

junk after document element
Location: http://localhost/Google/phpsqlajax_xml3.php
Line Number 2, Column 1:
^ 
I know the same error has been posted before, but I'm yet to find a solution that works for me. Any advice is appreciated! Here's my code, straight from google:

```
<?php
//require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");

$username="root";
$password="";
$database="my_db";



function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
{ 
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
return $xmlStr; 
} 

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';

?>
```

Comment: NOTE: my friend has had it work using EXACTLY that code. I'm using WAMP for my localhost; whereas he's using MAMP if that is any significance.

Comment: your parsetoxml() function is pointless, and is incorrect to boot. why not just use htmlspecialchars()?

Comment: I honestly just assumed that's how that's how the data was converted to an xml node if that makes sense? but looking again I've no idea why the name and address elements are done differently to the other three!

Comment: whats the output of the PHP-file?

Comment: What I want outputted comes at the end, but a lot of junk is there first, such as this.: <br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-deprecated' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\Google\phpsqlajax_xml3.php on line <i>21</i></th></tr>
............ etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else is stuck with a similar issue it was resolved by changing all the mysql statements to their mysqli equivalent.